# Editing argument in objective-c blocks

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I want to edit UIImage pointer in block but it's not allowed.

```
-(void)downloadImage:(NSURL *)url ofPointer:(UIImage *)imagePointer
{
    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    [SDWebImageManager.sharedManager downloadWithURL:url
                                             options:0
                                            progress:^(NSUInteger receivedSize, long long expectedSize) {}
                                           completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL finished) {
                                               imagePointer = image;
                                               [weakSelf setNeedsDisplay];
                                           }];
```

}

I tried to pass argument with __block but it's not allowed too.

`-(void)downloadImage:(NSURL *)url ofPointer:(__block UIImage *)imagePointer`

Is there any way to edit a pointer passed as an argument?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use a pointer to a pointer (`UIImage **`) as the image is an immutable object so even if you could change it inside the block it wouldn't have the effect you desire.

What you should probably do it use delegation or a callback block to pass the downloaded image out of the block to the instance that is going to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* do this, by passing a pointer to the pointer you want to set:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Dinsdale : NSObject
- (void)setThisPointer:(NSString *__autoreleasing *)s;
@end

@implementation Dinsdale

- (void)setThisPointer:(NSString *__autoreleasing *)s
{
    void (^b)(void) = ^{
        *s = @"Lemon curry?";
    };

    b();
}

@end

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        Dinsdale * d = [Dinsdale new];
        NSString * s = @"Semprimi!";
        [d setThisPointer:&s];
        NSLog(@"%@", s);    // Prints "Lemon curry?"

    }
    return 0;
}
```

but it would be better to just use a setter method:

```
-(void)downloadImageFromURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    [SDWebImageManager.sharedManager downloadWithURL:url
                                             options:0
                                            progress:^(NSUInteger receivedSize, long long expectedSize) {}
                                           completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL finished) {
                                               [weakSelf setWhateverImage:image]
                                               [weakSelf setNeedsDisplay];
                                           }];
}
```

Comment: Thanks Josh,

Great answer, but I can't pass a property as an argument

`[self downloadImage:imageURL ofPointer:&_imgUserPost1];`
ERR:Passing address of non-local object to __autoreleasing parameter for write-back

or

`[self downloadImage:imageURL ofPointer:&self.imgUserPost1];`
ERR:Address of property expression requested

Comment: Yes, don't do it that way. Use the setter in the block.

Comment: I can't do that too because which property will be set is uncertain. Thats the why i pass it as an argument.

Comment: You could pass the property name and use `setValue:forKey:`

Comment: A similar alternative is to pass another block that your -downloadWithURL:...completed: block can call.